# ALTERNATIVE TO APPENDROW OR HOW TO DUPLICATE ROWS TO SPREADSHEET

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I have the following code that can send the inputs values to a row in Google SpreadSheet. I want to send the values twice to the same spreadsheet (firts time on one row, the second time on the next row). I have copy the function that sends the values to the spreadsheet  (with some changes to not duplicate the function´s name). But I can only pass one time the values.
i think that the seocnd time the function crashes ( thats what I think). Do to some policies on software, I can only use pure JavaScript. Can I use an alternative to send the values to the same spreadsheet on separate rows? What alternative would you all recommend? I am sharing the Code.gs and HTML scripts. Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
  <form> 
   <table>
    <td>
          <tr>
           <td><label id="Date_01">Date</label></td>
           <td><input type="date" id="idDate"></td>
          </tr>
            <br>
          <tr>
           <td><label id="LabelAccount">Vendor´s Account</label></td>
           <td><select type="text" id="idAccount">
            <option>A0011</option>
            <option>A0022</option>
            <option>A0033</option>
            </select></td>
          </tr>
            <br>
          <tr>
           <td><label id="LabelVendorID">Vendor´s Identification Number</label></td>
           <td><select type="text" id="idVendor">
            <option>ID0044</option>
            <option>ID0055</option>
            <option>ID0066</option>
            </select></td>
          </tr>
          <br>
          <tr>
           <td><label id="LabelBranch">Vendor´s Branch</label></td>
            <td><select type="text" id="idBranch">            
            <option>BRANCH001</option>
            <option>BRANCH002</option>
            <option>BRANCH003</option>
            </select></td>
          </tr>  
     </td>
  </table> 
 </form>
     
  <form> 
<table>
<td>
      <tr>
            <caption style="color:#ffffff;font-family:arial black;font-size:15px; border:0px solid #1f3f79; background-color: #004481;">DETAILS</caption>
      </tr>     
          <tr>
           <td><label id="Label1000_01">DOC 1000_01</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id1000_01"></td>
           <td><label id="Label1000_02">DOC 1000_02</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id1000_02"></td>
           <td><label id="Label1000_03">DOC 1000_03</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id1000_03"></td>
           <td><label id="Label1000_04">DOC 1000_04</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id1000_04"></td>
           <td><label id="Label1000_05">DOC 1000_05</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id1000_05"></td>
         </tr>  
         <tr>
           <td><label id="Label2000_01">DOC 2000_01</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id2000_01"></td>
           <td><label id="Label2000_02">DOC 2000_02</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id2000_02"></td>
           <td><label id="Label2000_03">DOC 2000_03</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id2000_03"></td>
           <td><label id="Label2000_04">DOC 2000_04</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id2000_04"></td>
           <td><label id="Label2000_05">DOC 2000_05</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id2000_05"></td>
         </tr>           
         <tr>
           <td><label id="Label3000_01">DOC 3000_01</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id3000_01"></td>
           <td><label id="Label3000_02">DOC 3000_02</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id3000_02"></td>
           <td><label id="Label3000_03">DOC 3000_03</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id3000_03"></td>
           <td><label id="Label3000_04">DOC 3000_04</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id3000_04"></td>
           <td><label id="Label3000_05">DOC 3000_05</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id3000_05"></td>
         </tr>          
         <tr>
           <td><label id="Label4000_01">DOC 4000_01</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id4000_01"></td>
           <td><label id="Label4000_02">DOC 4000_02</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id4000_02"></td>
           <td><label id="Label4000_03">DOC 4000_03</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id4000_03"></td>
           <td><label id="Label4000_04">DOC 4000_04</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id4000_04"></td>
           <td><label id="Label4000_05">DOC 4000_05</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id4000_05"></td>
         </tr> 
         <tr>
           <td><label id="Label5000_01">DOC 5000_01</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id5000_01"></td>
           <td><label id="Label5000_02">DOC 5000_02</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id5000_02"></td>
           <td><label id="Label5000_03">DOC 5000_03</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id5000_03"></td>
           <td><label id="Label5000_04">DOC 5000_04</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id5000_04"></td>
           <td><label id="Label5000_05">DOC 5000_05</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id5000_05"></td>
         </tr> 
         <tr>
           <td><label id="Label6000_01">DOC 6000_01</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id6000_01"></td>
           <td><label id="Label6000_02">DOC 6000_02</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id6000_02"></td>
           <td><label id="Label6000_03">DOC 6000_03</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id6000_03"></td>
           <td><label id="Label6000_04">DOC 6000_04</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id6000_04"></td>
           <td><label id="Label6000_05">DOC 6000_05</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id6000_05"></td>
         </tr> 
         <tr>
           <td><label id="Label7000_01">DOC 7000_01</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id7000_01"></td>
           <td><label id="Label7000_02">DOC 7000_02</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id7000_02"></td>
           <td><label id="Label7000_03">DOC 7000_03</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id7000_03"></td>
           <td><label id="Label7000_04">DOC 7000_04</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id7000_04"></td>
           <td><label id="Label7000_05">DOC 7000_05</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id7000_05"></td>
         </tr> 
         <tr>
           <td><label id="Label8000_01">DOC 8000_01</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id8000_01"></td>
           <td><label id="Label8000_02">DOC 8000_02</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id8000_02"></td>
           <td><label id="Label8000_03">DOC 8000_03</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id8000_03"></td>
           <td><label id="Label8000_04">DOC 8000_04</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id8000_04"></td>
           <td><label id="Label8000_05">DOC 8000_05</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id8000_05"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><label id="Label9000_01">DOC 9000_01</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id9000_01"></td>
           <td><label id="Label9000_02">DOC 9000_02</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id9000_02"></td>
           <td><label id="Label9000_03">DOC 9000_03</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id9000_03"></td>
           <td><label id="Label9000_04">DOC 9000_04</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id9000_04"></td>
           <td><label id="Label9000_05">DOC 9000_05</label>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="id9000_05"></td>
         </tr> 
 </table>
  </form>
</td>

<script>
    function registerFullOperation(){
    var RegisterOps = {};
    
    RegisterOps.idDate = document.getElementById("idDate").value;
    RegisterOps.idAccount = document.getElementById("idAccount").value;
    RegisterOps.idVendor = document.getElementById("idVendor").value;
    RegisterOps.idBranch = document.getElementById("idBranch").value;
    RegisterOps.id1000_01 = document.getElementById("id1000_01").value;
    RegisterOps.id1000_02 = document.getElementById("id1000_02").value;
    RegisterOps.id1000_03 = document.getElementById("id1000_03").value;
    RegisterOps.id1000_04 = document.getElementById("id1000_04").value;
    RegisterOps.id1000_05 = document.getElementById("id1000_05").value;
    RegisterOps.id2000_01 = document.getElementById("id2000_01").value;
    RegisterOps.id2000_02 = document.getElementById("id2000_02").value;
    RegisterOps.id2000_03 = document.getElementById("id2000_03").value;
    RegisterOps.id2000_04 = document.getElementById("id2000_04").value;
    RegisterOps.id2000_05 = document.getElementById("id2000_05").value;
    RegisterOps.id3000_01 = document.getElementById("id3000_01").value;
    RegisterOps.id3000_02 = document.getElementById("id3000_02").value;
    RegisterOps.id3000_03 = document.getElementById("id3000_03").value;
    RegisterOps.id3000_04 = document.getElementById("id3000_04").value;
    RegisterOps.id3000_05 = document.getElementById("id3000_05").value;
    RegisterOps.id4000_01 = document.getElementById("id4000_01").value;
    RegisterOps.id4000_02 = document.getElementById("id4000_02").value;
    RegisterOps.id4000_03 = document.getElementById("id4000_03").value;
    RegisterOps.id4000_04 = document.getElementById("id4000_04").value;
    RegisterOps.id4000_05 = document.getElementById("id4000_05").value;
    RegisterOps.id5000_01 = document.getElementById("id5000_01").value;
    RegisterOps.id5000_02 = document.getElementById("id5000_02").value;
    RegisterOps.id5000_03 = document.getElementById("id5000_03").value;
    RegisterOps.id5000_04 = document.getElementById("id5000_04").value;
    RegisterOps.id5000_05 = document.getElementById("id5000_05").value;
    RegisterOps.id6000_01 = document.getElementById("id6000_01").value;
    RegisterOps.id6000_02 = document.getElementById("id6000_02").value;
    RegisterOps.id6000_03 = document.getElementById("id6000_03").value;
    RegisterOps.id6000_04 = document.getElementById("id6000_04").value;
    RegisterOps.id6000_05 = document.getElementById("id6000_05").value;
    RegisterOps.id7000_01 = document.getElementById("id7000_01").value;
    RegisterOps.id7000_02 = document.getElementById("id7000_02").value;
    RegisterOps.id7000_03 = document.getElementById("id7000_03").value;
    RegisterOps.id7000_04 = document.getElementById("id7000_04").value;
    RegisterOps.id7000_05 = document.getElementById("id7000_05").value;
    RegisterOps.id8000_01 = document.getElementById("id8000_01").value;
    RegisterOps.id8000_02 = document.getElementById("id8000_02").value;
    RegisterOps.id8000_03 = document.getElementById("id8000_03").value;
    RegisterOps.id8000_04 = document.getElementById("id8000_04").value;
    RegisterOps.id9000_01 = document.getElementById("id9000_01").value;
    RegisterOps.id9000_02 = document.getElementById("id9000_02").value;
    RegisterOps.id9000_03 = document.getElementById("id9000_03").value;
    RegisterOps.id9000_04 = document.getElementById("id9000_04").value;
    RegisterOps.id9000_05 = document.getElementById("id9000_05").value;
    google.script.run.registerFullOperation(RegisterOps); 
    }       
</script>

   <button id="idButton" onclick="registerFullOperation()">REGISTER</button>
```

GS

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("URL");
var sheetOps = ss.getSheetByName("SHEET 1");

  function registerFullOperation(RegisterOps){
sheet.appendRow([RegisterOps.idDate,RegisterOps.idAccount,RegisterOps.idVendor,RegisterOps.idBranch,RegisterOps.id1000_01,RegisterOps.id1000_02,RegisterOps.id1000_03,RegisterOps.id1000_04,RegisterOps.id1000_05,RegisterOps.id2000_01,RegisterOps.id2000_02,RegisterOps.id2000_03,RegisterOps.id2000_04,RegisterOps.id2000_05,RegisterOps.id3000_01,RegisterOps.id3000_02,RegisterOps.id3000_03,RegisterOps.id3000_04,RegisterOps.id3000_05,RegisterOps.id4000_01,RegisterOps.id4000_02,RegisterOps.id4000_03,RegisterOps.id4000_04,RegisterOps.id4000_05,RegisterOps.id5000_01,RegisterOps.id5000_02,RegisterOps.id5000_03,RegisterOps.id5000_04,RegisterOps.id5000_05,RegisterOps.id6000_01,RegisterOps.id6000_02,RegisterOps.id6000_03,RegisterOps.id6000_04,RegisterOps.id6000_05,RegisterOps.id7000_01,RegisterOps.id7000_02,RegisterOps.id7000_03,RegisterOps.id7000_04,RegisterOps.id7000_05,RegisterOps.id8000_01,RegisterOps.id8000_02,RegisterOps.id8000_03,RegisterOps.id8000_04,RegisterOps.id8000_05,RegisterOps.id9000_01,RegisterOps.id9000_02,RegisterOps.id9000_03,RegisterOps.id9000_04,RegisterOps.id9000_05]);}
```

[image: SPREADSHEET RESULT]

[image]

Comment: About `But I can only pass one time the values.`, when I saw your showing script, I think that even when you click the button, no script is run. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your script. How about this?

Comment: Can you verify first if the provided html or script code is correct and running, similarly I was unable to replicate it since clicking the button does nothing as well on my end.

Comment: An apology, when pasting the code, I pasted it incorrectly. It is already corrected to my original code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the reason the button doesn't work is it should be `registerFullOperation()`

```
<button id="idButton" onclick="registerFullOperation()">REGISTER</button>
```

Secondly, to copy 2 rows

```
let row = [RegisterOps.idDate,RegisterOps.idAccount,RegisterOps.idVendor,RegisterOps.idBranch,RegisterOps.id1000_01,RegisterOps.id1000_02,RegisterOps.id1000_03,RegisterOps.id1000_04,RegisterOps.id1000_05,RegisterOps.id2000_01,RegisterOps.id2000_02,RegisterOps.id2000_03,RegisterOps.id2000_04,RegisterOps.id2000_05,RegisterOps.id3000_01,RegisterOps.id3000_02,RegisterOps.id3000_03,RegisterOps.id3000_04,RegisterOps.id3000_05,RegisterOps.id4000_01,RegisterOps.id4000_02,RegisterOps.id4000_03,RegisterOps.id4000_04,RegisterOps.id4000_05,RegisterOps.id5000_01,RegisterOps.id5000_02,RegisterOps.id5000_03,RegisterOps.id5000_04,RegisterOps.id5000_05,RegisterOps.id6000_01,RegisterOps.id6000_02,RegisterOps.id6000_03,RegisterOps.id6000_04,RegisterOps.id6000_05,RegisterOps.id7000_01,RegisterOps.id7000_02,RegisterOps.id7000_03,RegisterOps.id7000_04,RegisterOps.id7000_05,RegisterOps.id8000_01,RegisterOps.id8000_02,RegisterOps.id8000_03,RegisterOps.id8000_04,RegisterOps.id8000_05,RegisterOps.id9000_01,RegisterOps.id9000_02,RegisterOps.id9000_03,RegisterOps.id9000_04,RegisterOps.id9000_05,];
let rows = [row,row];
sheetOps.getRange(sheetOps.getLastRow()+1,1,rows.length,rows[0].length).setValues(rows);
```

However if any of your object properties are a Date, convert to string before passing back to server.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I was able to get the code running. The data is sent in two rows, but I can't get it to start on the next empty row. It overwrites the data in the sheet headers, and the next click the following data is overwritten on the previous one and so on. I added a new image with the result. Any other comment that can help me, I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Oops, sorry, i flipped row and column in the last line.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it very much. Have a great day.